# Maya channelBox check

Tags: python, attributes, maya

Hello everyone, I need your help if you have time...
I'm trying to write a script to understand which attribute is available in the channelBox when the user selection and object in Maya scene.

I have this which doesn't work...

```
import maya.cmds as mc

usersel = []
usersel = mc.ls(sl=True, dag=False, s=0)

chl = mc.listAttr(usersel)

for x in chl:
    if ("rotateX") ==1:
        print ('yes')
    else:
        print ('not')
```

thanks in advance

Comment: why not using the channelBox command ?

Comment: Thanks DrWeeny, but I dont actually know how to do it ...